# Is there a way to import content from a separate file?

Tags: document-configuration

I have the content in a separate text file. Is it possible to import that between the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`? Is there an include option in LaTeX? Thank you!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/263192

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project

Comment: By "import", do you mean to read it into the document "as is" or do you mean, as in the case of structured data files, to read in content as a data array, so that individual pieces of the imported data can be extracted?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit cryptic, but if I understand you correctly you want a `.tex` file included. So you either use the `\include{foo.tex}` or `\input{foo.tex}` command.

Comment: Warning -- `\include` always starts a new page; `\input` doesn't.  And if the extension is `.tex`, it doesn't have to be stated.